# Moving an object in an area

Tags: motor

I am planning to build a little game and I would need to move a small magnet inside a rectangular area. Ideally I would be able to control movement arbitrarily e.g. using a joystick. 
I am trying to find a way of doing this, something like an actuator, I guess, but allowing movement in 2D.
Any suggestions on which parts to use?

Edit : in brief, what I'm trying to do is this. I have a piece of plywood, underneath which I want to put a magnet. The magnet will be moveable using a joystick (everything controlled through an Arduino) and will be used to move a magnetised figurine on the other side of the plywood. I guess in term of precision of movement I am not looking for extreme precision, having something accurate to 2-3mm would be absolutely fine. Haven't really thought of speed... But not looking for extreme high speeds.

Comment: Two linear axes perpendicular to each other, made of pulleys (like most 3D printers) or of nuts on threaded rods. Or two rotational axes on top of each other, like a SCARA robot. Your question is really broad. You didn't explain enough, what you are trying to achieve. We don't know nothing about your requirements. And maybe this is better fit for the robotics SE site, since your question is not about Arduino.

Comment: Hi @chrisl, thank you for your comment. What type of details would help?

Comment: First an overview, what you are trying to achieve here. I'm sure moving a magnet is not all to the story. Then you need to think about how fast and precise the magnet should move. When using linear axes, pulleys are much faster, threaded rods are more precise. And I assume there is something important lying in the fact, that you try to move a magnet. Do you want to move it with another magnet from under a table? These information are important for designing a fitting solution.

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question, This question is #20,000 question in Arduino SE.

Comment: @chrisl thank you. I added a few more details. Anyways your suggestions are already a great start, I guess you could convert that to an answer?

Comment: @ElectronSurf, it is not. many questions are deleted and this will be deleted too after a month or so

Comment: @nico, I'm looking at this history of this question.  Keep in mind [all stack exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) (not just Arduino) are best used 1 question at a time.  And often it is best to try something first then come here and ask question if that attempt did not work out.  If you need to discuss an Arduino project and get some direction it may be better to try forum.arduino.cc.  Look at [this specific thread](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=288556.0) and search or others that are similar.  Then come back here with specific questions after trying something.

Comment: @st2000 I know, I've been using StackExchange for a very long time. You are right, I should have specified what I did try, but since I could not really find a proper way of looking for this I was just looking for some inspiration. Probably arduino forum would have been a better fit, anyway I got enough ideas from the answer and hopefully someone else facing a similar problem will benefit from this as well.

Comment: Well put.  I would search for project involving moving chess pieces with electromagnets like this one: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/ghost-chess-electromagnets-move-pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to think about your axes configuration, then about the actual implementation. I for example can directly think of 2 options:

- You could arrange your axes perpendicular to each other, like a Cartesian coordinate system. Here you might need more parts to build it, than with other arrangements, though it is a sturdy system and the positions and paths are easily to calculate. For implementation there are 2 common ways, both using stepper motors in most cases:

  - You could let the magnet travel on the 2 perpendicular axes pulled by a belt and stepper motor for each axis. As you have to mount one axes onto the other, you might need to use 2 stepper motors (one for each side) for the first axis (depending on your dimensions, how smooth the axes glide and how much force is introduced by dragging the figurine). This approach is mostly used by 3D Printers, since they need rather fast movement, which is also rather precise, but don't need to accommodate high forces.
  - Instead of belts and pulleys you could use threaded rods for each axis. The magnet is mounted on nuts on these rods. Rotating the rots will move the magnet over the axis, since the magnet is fixed in it's orientation. The precision is highly dependent on the used rods, but all in all it is often more precise, than belts. But it is also way slower.
- You could use only rotational axes, like a SCARA robot. It has a rod on a rotational axis and another axis at the end of it. This approach might use less parts, than the Cartesian approach, but you need good servos to have precise and jitter-free positioning (though you could also go for a geared stepper motor here). Also the arm of the robot can look out under the field quite a bit, when positioning it to the far one side.

---

All of the above approaches can be way more precise, than you need it. They are all viable options.

I personally would go the first way, Cartesian axes with belts and pulleys. The principle is straight forward and you can easily hide it under your piece of plywood (including a margin for all the mechanical stuff of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Extremely helpful and gave me some good directions to look at